# Calcular 2 totais diferentes de elementos de um array de acordo com o valor de outra propriedade

Tags: javascript, array, filter

Meu objetivo é separar a soma dos salários só das mulheres em um `filter` + `reduce` e a soma dos salários dos homens em outro utilizando também `filter` + `reduce`.

O `console.log(salarioMulher)` na última linha está fazendo a soma total dos salários, poderiam me ajudar a fazer a soma específica feminina e masculina?

```js
const funcionarios = [
    { nome: "Joany", salario: 4500, sexo: "F"},
    { nome: 'Junior', salario: 4500, sexo: 'M'},
    { nome: 'Julio', salario: 3500, sexo: 'M'},
    { nome: 'Grazy', salario: 3000, sexo: 'F'},
    { nome: 'Rafael', salario: 6000, sexo: 'M'},
    { nome: 'Artur', salario: 7800, sexo: 'M'},
    { nome: 'Ana', salario: 3300, sexo: 'F'},
    { nome: 'Bianca', salario: 12500, sexo: 'F'},
    { nome: 'José', salario: 8400, sexo: 'M'},
    { nome: 'Maria', salario: 5500, sexo: 'F'}   
]
 
JSON.stringify(funcionarios)
 
const apenasMulher = a => a.sexo === 'F' 
const apenasHomem = a => a.sexo === 'M'
 
 
const somaSalario = sal => sal.salario
const totalSalario = (sal, salAtual) => {
return sal + salAtual   
}
 
const arraySalario = funcionarios.map(somaSalario)
const salarioMulher = arraySalario.reduce(totalSalario)
 
 
const func = funcionarios.filter(apenasMulher)
console.log(func)
console.log(salarioMulher)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você já criou as funções para filtrar homens e mulheres, outra para mapear cada funcionário com seu respectivo salário e outra para calcular a soma dos elementos de um array. Só faltou combiná-las na ordem certa:

```js
const funcionarios = [
    { nome: "Joany", salario: 4500, sexo: "F"},
    { nome: 'Junior', salario: 4500, sexo: 'M'},
    { nome: 'Julio', salario: 3500, sexo: 'M'},
    { nome: 'Grazy', salario: 3000, sexo: 'F'},
    { nome: 'Rafael', salario: 6000, sexo: 'M'},
    { nome: 'Artur', salario: 7800, sexo: 'M'},
    { nome: 'Ana', salario: 3300, sexo: 'F'},
    { nome: 'Bianca', salario: 12500, sexo: 'F'},
    { nome: 'José', salario: 8400, sexo: 'M'},
    { nome: 'Maria', salario: 5500, sexo: 'F'}   
];

const apenasMulher = a => a.sexo === 'F';
const apenasHomem = a => a.sexo === 'M';

// mudei o nome para "obtemSalario" pois "somaSalario" não é bem o que ela faz
const obtemSalario = sal => sal.salario;
const totalSalario = (sal, salAtual) => {
    return sal + salAtual;
};

let totalMulheres = funcionarios.filter(apenasMulher).map(obtemSalario).reduce(totalSalario);
let totalHomens = funcionarios.filter(apenasHomem).map(obtemSalario).reduce(totalSalario);
console.log(totalMulheres);
console.log(totalHomens);
```

Ou seja, primeiro você filtra pelo critério desejado (`filter` para ter só homens, ou só mulheres), depois mapeia-os para os seus salários (`map`), e só depois você soma tudo (`reduce`).

No seu código você fez `funcionarios.map(somaSalario)`, ou seja, pegou os salários de todos os funcionários, e em seguida somou tudo (faltou o `filter` para filtrar somente as mulheres). Na verdade você chamou o `filter` **depois**, mas aí já não adianta porque o total já havia sido calculado.

Repare também que mudei o nome da função `somaSalario` para `obtemSalario`, pois ela não estava somando nada, só estava servindo para mapear cada funcionário para seu respectivo salário. Pode parecer um detalhe besta, mas [dar nomes melhores ajuda na hora de programar](https://hackernoon.com/the-art-of-naming-variables-52f44de00aad).

Também coloquei ponto-e-vírgula no final das linhas. Pode parecer "frescura", e sei que o JavaScript "aceita" o código sem ponto e vírgula e "funciona", mas isso evita algumas situações bizarras que podem ocorrer se você não usá-los, como [essa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1169596) e [essa](/q/432960/112052) (veja mais sobre isso [aqui](/q/3341/112052)).

---

#### Alternativas

Só pra constar que há outras alternativas, algumas até eliminando a necessidade do `filter` e/ou do `map`:

```
function somar(dados, campo, sexo) {
    // usando filter, map e reduce
    //return dados.filter(e => e.sexo === sexo).map(e => e[campo]).reduce((a, b) => a + b);
    // ou sem o map
    //return dados.filter(e => e.sexo === sexo).reduce((a, b) => a + b[campo], 0);
    // ou só com reduce
    return dados.reduce((a, b) => a + (b.sexo === sexo ? b[campo] : 0), 0);
}

console.log(somar(funcionarios, 'salario', 'F')); // totalMulheres
console.log(somar(funcionarios, 'salario', 'M')); // totalHomens
```

Ou ainda, retornando um objeto com ambos os totais:

```
let { totalHomens, totalMulheres } = funcionarios.reduce(function (a, b) {
    if (b.sexo === 'M') {
        a.totalHomens += b.salario;
    } else if (b.sexo === 'F') {
        a.totalMulheres += b.salario;
    }
    return a;
}, { totalHomens: 0, totalMulheres: 0 });

console.log(totalMulheres);
console.log(totalHomens);
```

Esse último em particular eu já considero um exagero (e um certo abuso de `reduce`), mas fica como curiosidade...

---

### Sem `filter`/`map`/`reduce`

Mas será que precisava de tudo isso? Cada chamada de [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) e [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) percorre os elementos do array e retorna **outro** array, e [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) faz várias chamadas do *callback* `totalSalario` para fazer uma simples soma. Ou seja, não só você está percorrendo várias vezes os mesmos elementos, como ainda está criando várias estruturas intermediárias à toa.

Eu acho muito mais simples fazer apenas um `for`:

```js
const funcionarios = [
    { nome: "Joany", salario: 4500, sexo: "F"},
    { nome: 'Junior', salario: 4500, sexo: 'M'},
    { nome: 'Julio', salario: 3500, sexo: 'M'},
    { nome: 'Grazy', salario: 3000, sexo: 'F'},
    { nome: 'Rafael', salario: 6000, sexo: 'M'},
    { nome: 'Artur', salario: 7800, sexo: 'M'},
    { nome: 'Ana', salario: 3300, sexo: 'F'},
    { nome: 'Bianca', salario: 12500, sexo: 'F'},
    { nome: 'José', salario: 8400, sexo: 'M'},
    { nome: 'Maria', salario: 5500, sexo: 'F'}   
];

let totalHomens = 0;
let totalMulheres = 0;
for (const func of funcionarios) {
    switch(func.sexo) {
        case 'M':
            totalHomens += func.salario;
            break;
        case 'F':
            totalMulheres += func.salario;
            break;
    }
}
console.log(totalMulheres);
console.log(totalHomens);
```

Comment: muito obrigado, e obrigado também por dar outras alternativas, faço ciência da computação mas não vi programação direito ainda, to no 2 periodo e a faculdade ta parada, tô aproveitando pra fazer um curso, pedi ajuda com as funções especificas do array pois eu tinha um pouco de dúvida no funcionamento do map e reduce, pelo visto foi só um erro de digitação no final, obrigado pelas alternativas fora a parte usando laço :)

Comment: @JuniorJarismar Se a resposta resolveu o seu problema, vc pode aceitá-la, [**veja aqui**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) como e porque fazê-lo. Não é obrigatório, mas é uma boa prática do site, para indicar a futuros visitantes que aquilo resolveu o problema. Não esqueça que [**vc também pode votar**](/help/privileges/vote-up) na resposta, caso tenha achado útil.